# Fetch non-empty cells from .xls file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i am new to python. i want to fetch the values from the cells & empty cells should be discarded.
i want to loop through rows & columns & assign to list

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelFile
from pandas import ExcelWriter

df=pd.read_excel('16Junedata_03062020_80163767_action_03062020_80163767_2624_01.xls', sheet_name='Sheet4')
#newdf = df.fillna({'business_day':0,'zone_id':0,'site_id':0,'device_id':0})
#newdf = df.fillna(method="ffill")
z_id= df['zone_id']
d_id= df['device_id']
s_id= df['site_id']
vst= df['visit_start_time']
# print(z_id)
# print(d_id)
# print(s_id)

for a,zone_id in z_id.iteritems():
        for b,site_id in s_id.iteritems():
            print(site_id)
```

Comment: Please Don't include images instead add re-producable data sample that can be copy pasted & incude the expected output in the post.

Comment: you don't need to lop and you don't need to import all of those libraries. You have the right idea with `fillna()` Just read the data in and `fillna()` on the entire dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of non NaN values using below code, this is only for one column:

```
zone_id_updated = []
for item in df.zone_id.iteritems():
    if pd.isna(item[1])==False:
        zone_id_updated.append(item[1])
```

Similarly can be done for other columns.